# Set vim setting for all programming language filetypes

Tags: vim

My system has some default vim settings that make no sense to use on programming language files. I'd like to change my `formatoptions` setting for any buffer with a programming language filetype.

I had been adding an `autocmd` to my .vimrc for each file extension:

```
au FileType python,c,cpp,java setlocal formatoptions=crql
```

But it's getting annoying to maintain this list. How can I configure settings for all programming language filetypes (`c`, `cpp`, `python`, `java`...) and possibly all structured syntaxes (`xml`, `yaml`, `cfg`, `diff`...), but *not* for miscellaneous filetypes like `gitcommit` and no filetype? Do I need to maintain my own blacklist?

Comment: Do you have any conception of *how many* languages and structured file types there are? How sure are you that they can be programmatically recognized? Mind you, `vim` won't support them all, but I bet the list it *does* support has room for some ambiguity.

Comment: I don't need to recognize every programming language, I just want every programming language vim is already configured with a filetype for to have certain settings.

Comment: Do you *really* work with the hundreds of languages supported by Vim?

Comment: I don't know about hundreds, but I'm running into more of them every few days. ruby, go, vala, html, perl, lisp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off turning on for everything, then selectively turning them off for the filetype's where it's a problem.

Comment: This is probably what I'll end up doing. I looked through the whole list of ftplugins, and almost all of them are structured syntaxes where the 't' option doesn't make sense.